# Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $105$ with the property that $G$ has exactly one subgroup for each divisor of $105$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

Gallian's "Contemporary Abstract Algebra", chapter 7 problem 54

> Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $105$ with the property that $G$ has exactly one subgroup for each divisor of $105$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic

Sylow theorems, normal subgroups, and factor groups have not been covered yet at this point in the book, so I suspect they are not needed.

Pick $\alpha \in G $ such that $\alpha$ is not in any of the subgroups of order $1, 3, 5, \dots 35$. Then it would have to have order 105 by Lagrange. We know such an $\alpha$ exists because $|H_1| + |H_3| + \dots + |H_{35}| \leq 1+3+5+7+15+21+35 < 105 = |G|$, where $H_i$ denotes the subgroup of order $i$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct; note that you have an equality, not inequality, between the sum of the orders. The inequality is when you compare $|\cup H_i|$ with $\sum |H_i|$. The latter is clearly *strictly larger* than the former, since the subgroups are never pairwise disjoint.